# How to connect docker container in WSL2 by localhost

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Windows10: Insider preview 18970.1005

I can't connect to docker container running on WSL2 by localhost.
localhost:3306 is refused.

But, (eth0 ip):3306 is connect successfully.

`nc -l 8000` and `localhost:8000` is ok too.

How I connect to docker container?

Comment: IIRC, WSL2 runs in a different network context. Using `localhost` would not be possible.

Comment: See this video about [Docker Desktop Integration with WSL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_PpmELU_PM).